# Nginx stops proxy_cache under siege or with curl request when page's cache is out of date

Tags: nginx, cache

I try to serve an index page with nginx, using it's proxy_cache functionality. Everything works fine regards ordinary browsing with broswers. But when I try to get page's content with curl or when I use siege on the index page, nginx begins to work not as I have expected. It passes the request further to apache when page's cache is out of date.

I can't understand, why nginx doesn't create a new cache of the index page when it was requested with curl or siege?

Here is a part of nginx.conf:

```
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=2 keys_zone=pagecache:100m inactive=1m max_size=500m;

    location = / {
            set $o_uri $request_uri;

            if ( $http_cookie !~ "mytestcookie" ) {
                    rewrite ^ /ng_cache last;
            }

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:88;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /ng_cache {
            internal;

            root /home/$host/www;

            proxy_cache             pagecache;
            proxy_cache_valid       200 301 302 304 1m;
            proxy_hide_header       "Set-Cookie";
            proxy_ignore_headers    "Cache-Control" "Expires";

            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:88$o_uri;
            proxy_set_header        Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie` line in your config suggests that your backend returns Set-Cookie header, which will prevent nginx from caching such a response [by default](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_valid). You likely want to add Set-Cookie to `proxy_ignore_headers` in your config:

```
proxy_ignore_headers    Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
```

See [docs](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_ignore_headers) for details.